# Merging is called only once in merge sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm

In this code the line 6 returns the smallest left part of the Array A which can not be further broken(base case) & same for 7th line where it cuts right part of Array  A to smallest subarray. What i want to ask is Merge in line 8 is called just one time. How does it merge all the small subarrays multiple time. Till we get the sorted A back.

Say i have A[] = {34,567,87,989,0,43,8,233};

line 6th will return small subarrays containing 34,567,87,989 separately & line 7 returns 0,43,8,233
now Merge in line 8 is called only once how can it these subarrays multiple times.

For example Merge 34, 567 and 0,43 then Merge subarray containing 34,567 and 87,989 and so on.

```
1)Merge-Sort(A,p,r)
2)if p==r 
3)   return 
4)else
5)   q= floor((p+r)/2)
6)   Merge-Sort(A,p,q)
7)   Merge-Sort(A,q+1,r)
8)   Merge(A,p,q,r)
```

Comment: i know that it called with height of tree -1 times but how @MateuszDymczyk

Comment: You'll get the best understanding if you write the numbers on index cards, and then follow the directions of your algorithm, doing the operations by hand. The crucial thing is to follow the directions _exactly_. Don't attempt to interpret or act upon what you _think_ the calls mean, just follow the directions literally. Each time you get to a function call, jot it down (with its arguments) on a notepad, each time you finish the function, cross it off so you can see where you returned to.

Answer (score 1):

> Merge in line 8 is called only once how can it use these subarrays multiple times?

Since `Merge` is called at each level where the subarray to be sorted has more than one element, `Merge` would be passed overlapping portions of the same sub-array at the stages of the algorithm working on "deeper" invocation levels.

In your example, merge will be called like this:

```
Merge(0, 0, 1)             -- Level 3
Merge(1, 1, 2)             -- Level 3
    Merge(0, 1, 2)         -- Level 2
Merge(2, 2, 3)             -- Level 3
Merge(3, 3, 4)             -- Level 3
    Merge(2, 3, 4)         -- Level 2
        Merge(0, 2, 4)     -- Level 1
Merge(4, 4, 5)             -- Level 3
Merge(5, 5, 6)             -- Level 3
    Merge(4, 5, 6)         -- Level 2
Merge(6, 6, 7)             -- Level 3
Merge(7, 7, 8)             -- Level 3
    Merge(6, 7, 8)         -- Level 2
        Merge(4, 6, 8)     -- Level 1
            Merge(0, 4, 8) -- Level 0
```

I indented the calls to show their location on the stack of invocations.

You can see that each half of the array is merged over several times. Before the final merge on the last line, the halves of the left sub-array are merged on line 7. The hales of the first half are in turn merged on lines 3 and 6. Finally, merges on lines 1, 2, 4, and 5 merge "unit arrays" that are automatically sorted because they have only one element.

Answer (score 0):

@dasblinkenlight is correct but I like to visualise merge sort (and most recursions) as a tree. For instance for input `[4,3,2,1]` you will have:

```
1.   [4,3,2,1]    <- initial invocation will call Merge-Sort() twice and Merge() once
2.   /       \    <- we call Merge-Sort for both halves
3. [4,3]   [2,1]  <- each of those nodes will call again Merge-Sort() twice and Merge() once after their respective Merge-Sort() return
4. /   \   /   \  <- for each node we again call Merge-Sort() for both halfs
5. [4] [3] [2] [1] <- base cases, no calls to Merge() or Merge-Sort(), we go back up the tree
```

As you can see we call `Merge()` at each node that's not a leaf, that means we will have `2^lg(n) - 1` calls to `Merge()`.

That's how recursion works, you go inside the same function and when you come back up the tree you continue from the spot where you did your recursive calls in your case `Merge-Sort(A,p,q)` or `Merge-Sort(A,q+1,r)`.